# How to comparing 2 data sets and decide how good the similiarity is?

Tags: r, distributions

say I have 2 data sets of different length. How can I decide if these 2 datasets are similar in shape? Take the following data sets for instance. DT1 is a random series, and DT2 is sampling from DT1, to make sure DT1, and DT2 has a certain level of similarity.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
DT1 <- data.frame(DATA=runif(100, min=1,max=100)) # length 100
DT2 <- data.frame(DATA=DT1[sample(100, 60),])     # length 60


ggplot(DT1, aes(DATA)) + geom_density()
ggplot(DT2, aes(DATA)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: I am thinking of transferring it into CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function), making it monotonically increasing. Then `cor.test` it. Pls feel free to advise.

Comment: (1) `cor.test` will give (very) wrong results; it isn't applicable to such data because the sorting of the data induces extremely strong dependencies within each dataset that `cor.test` assumes are not there. (2) What is your actual problem?  Does it involve comparing a subset of a sample to the sample or not?

Comment: Sorry if I misled. I'm looking for a reliable way of comparing 2 data sets which are obviously similar in shape of density.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ks for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.  A $\chi^2$ test, provided it is properly constructed, will also work in many cases.  Less formally, a standard exploratory tool to compare the distributions of datasets is a [qq plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=qq+plot).

Comment: As an amateur to the statistics, I find it so interesting and attractive. Would like to share what I read based on your advice. KS test is to compare 2 series of data and decide if these 2 series come from the same distribution based on the validity of the null hypothesis. In that case, the result would be more solid if I normalize the series independently and then apply the KS test. Thanks,  @whuber, I do get one more new piece of knowledge.